# How can I auto reload html page based on the value assigned to the session?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

How can I auto reload html page based on the value assigned to the session?

```
if ($_SESSION["LoadPage"])
{
//Reload my html page
}
```

I know how to use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >` but it cannot start auto refresh itself without someone to refresh

Please anyone can help me

Comment: Before any html output you can use php `header("Refresh:5");` if you really need to use meta then wrap that into your if statement from the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use location.reload(); function of the javascript for this.

use string concatenation with script and php

```
 <?php
     if ($_SESSION["LoadPage"])
   {
 ?> 
      <script>
      location.reload();//Reload my html page
      </script>
  <?php
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: This is not a good practice. if you use php then stick on PHP

Comment: One more question please, how do that codes of refresh can affect another tab with same page opened? for example if I open mypage.php in first tab and then refresh it, I need that page to auto affect another second tab of mypage.php to be refreshed automatically. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: This is not possible i guess.

Comment: It's possible, but its an entirely different question from what the OP originally asked and got answers for

Answer (score 0):

You could try php's header location. Or go a javascript route with location.href.

If you use `header()` make sure the following code is *before* any output.

In both cases (php or javascript) you want to make sure you unset (or otherwise clear) your session var so you don't run into a circular loop.

`header()` way:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["LoadPage"]))
{
   unset( $_SESSION["LoadPage"] );
   
   //Reload my html page
   header("location: mypage.php");
}
```

For the javascript way, you want to make sure your script will run after page load. The js way might be preferable to avoid a "redirection warning" from the browser, if applicable.

JS way:

Here I just attach the event to the html body tag, but you could create a more formal event listener if you want.

```
<body <?php 

if ( isset($_SESSION["LoadPage"]) ) {
   unset( $_SESSION["LoadPage"] );
   ?>onload='location.href="mypage.php"';<?php
}
?>>
```

Comment: One more question please, how do that codes of refresh can affect another tab with same page opened? for example if I open mypage.php in first tab and then refresh it, I need that page to auto affect another second tab of mypage.php to be refreshed automatically. Is it possible to do that?